# Sort array excluding elements

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array of elements of a custom type that I display in a tableview.
Each element has properties and especially a "level" one (0, 1, 2 or 3 as Int)

**What I want to do :**
I want to sort these elements by their level but by only displaying level 3 elements at the top of the tableview, and ignore other elements of level < 3.

**What I have tried** :
- `self.elements.sort(by: { $0.level! > $1.level! })`

=> All events are sorted

- `if element.level! > 2 {
   self.elements.sort(by: { $0.level! > $1.level! })
  }`

=> Not working

I don't really know what to do… any idea ? 

Thank you !

**EDIT**

Sorry I may have not be very clear:
I have an array of elements that I first sort by distance to the user and then want only level 3 elements to be at the top of the tableview.
And Ideally I would like these level 3 elements to also be sorted by distance.

 --> The output I want : elements sorted by distance, with level 3 elements at the top and I also want these level 3 elements to be sorted by distance 

(Sorry English is not my first language)

Comment: You need a combination of `filter` and `sort`

Comment: I don't understand your description. If you want only elements of level 3, that's filtering, how does sorting come into play? Please show an example of your data, and an example of the output that you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
self.elements.sort(by: { $0.level! > $1.level! }) 

var newArr = self.elements.filter({$0.level > 2})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have to deal with this kind of actions that can be recurrent and very specific, I encourage you to create extensions that are reusable.

There is an example:

> Your CustomClass (for example purpose only)

```
class CustomClass {
    var text: String!
    var level: Int!

    convenience init(text: String, level: Int) {
        self.init()

        self.text = text
        self.level = level
    }
}
```

> One extension method model (can be used again and modify)

```
extension Array where Element:CustomClass {
    mutating func sortWithFilter(minLevel: Int) {
        let list = self.sorted(by: { $0.level > $1.level})

        self = list.filter( { $0.level > minLevel })
    }
}
```

> Usage:

```
// Create array with your CustomClass

var array = [CustomClass]()

// Add some data

array.append(CustomClass(text: "info1", level: 1))
array.append(CustomClass(text: "info2", level: 3))
array.append(CustomClass(text: "info3", level: 2))
array.append(CustomClass(text: "info4", level: 3))
array.append(CustomClass(text: "info5", level: 0))

// Use our new extension method

array.sortWithFilter(minLevel: 2)
```

> Output:

```
text : info2 , level : 3 
text : info4 , level : 3
```

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you need to show only level 3 objects then no need to sort them, just filter them as below and done. because you are showing only 3 level empty other object will ignore

```
elements.filter({$0.level == 3})
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to accomplish this by adding level 3 elements to a different array. Then I sort both array by distance and finally I combine them to display elements in the tableview.

Thank you for the help guys !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have the following struct...

```
struct SomeStruct: CustomStringConvertible {
    var level: Int
    // create a random distance for demonstration
    let distance = Double(arc4random_uniform(100))

    var description: String {
        return "Level: \(level), Distance: \(distance)"
    }
}
```

And an array of those structs...

```
var arrayOfStructs = [
    SomeStruct(level: 3),
    SomeStruct(level: 1),
    SomeStruct(level: 1),
    SomeStruct(level: 2),
    SomeStruct(level: 1),
    SomeStruct(level: 3),
    SomeStruct(level: 3),
    SomeStruct(level: 2),
]
```

You can sort this array with your criteria like this:

```
arrayOfStructs.sort {
   ($0.level == 3 || $1.level == 3 && $0.level != $1.level) ? ($0.level == 3) : ($0.distance < $1.distance)
}
```

Then `arrayOfStructs.forEach { print($0) }` results in the following:

```
Level: 3, Distance: 38.0
Level: 3, Distance: 60.0
Level: 3, Distance: 75.0
Level: 1, Distance: 15.0
Level: 2, Distance: 23.0
Level: 2, Distance: 52.0
Level: 1, Distance: 65.0
Level: 1, Distance: 78.0
```